# Prevent Players From Stealing From Item Frames

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I have item frames right in front of a player, and still keep them from stealing the items from the item frame(s)? 
[I don't want to have to use the `/clear` command to just clear the item from the player's inventory when they obtain it.]

Comment: Wait, ignore my last comment. I forgot it only works if you are on a server with protection.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `Invulnerable` to true to prevent an item frame from both providing the player with an item as well as preventing the player from breaking the item frame by punching it.

```
/entitydata @e[type=ItemFrame,c=1] {Invulnerable:1b}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people wanting to make all item frames invincible, just use

`/execute as @e[type=minecraft:item_frame] run data merge entity @s {Invulnerable:1b}`

Answer (score -2):

Put the player in adventure mode. Players in adventure mode are not able to break item frames. Breaking entities in adventure was a [bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-579) and is resolved based on the bug tracker.

Comment: That bug is resolved as "Working as Intended", not "Fixed". Adventure mode players can still break item frames.